# Can we extract the C structures layout from the (debuggable) compiled code?

Tags: c, struct

I need to dump a struct layout in a file and recreate the structure again by reading that file in another code later.
In general, I noticed that the compiler may not save the full structure layout. Is there a way to do the same?

This is required for multicore implementation, communication is needed between two programs, and datatype is defined only in one program, the program wants to transfer the datatype information to another program on a different core so that other programs can read the data.
Unfortunately, the data type is a complex nested structure that is not predefined.

Comment: It sounds like you are compiling both programs. Why not just use the same header file containing the struct in both programs.

Comment: Try `llvm-dwarfdump yourfile.o`.

Comment: "I noticed that the compiler **may** not save the full structure layout." It never saves information about the struct definition. Only the program knows the definition. So when using binary files like that, it's your responsibility to make sure that both programs use the same definition

Comment: Which debugger and which compiler?  Have the debug symbols been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard length types (included in `<stdint.h>)` and packed structures avoiding bitfields to let your structure portable across compiler.
If you need cross-CPU to you maybe have to consider also the endianess: socket function like hton() and vice versa can do the job.

You may also consider to write a file in an human readable format, like json, and parse it on the other side.